# Extract a year number from a string that is surrounded by special characters

Tags: r, regex

What's a good way to extract only the number 2007 from the following string:

```
some_string <- "1_2_start_2007_3_end"
```

The pattern to detect the year number in my case would be:

- 4 digits
- surrounded by "_"

I am quite new to using regular expressions. I tried the following:

```
 regexp <- "_+[0-9]+_"
 names <- str_extract(files, regexp)
```

But this does not take into account that there are always 4 digits and outputs the underlines as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use regex lookbehind to specify the `_` and extract the 4 digits that follow

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(some_string, "(?<=_)\\d{4}")
#[1] "2007"
```

If the pattern also shows `-` both before and after the 4 digits, then use regex lookahead as well

```
str_extract(some_string, "(?<=_)\\d{4}(?=_)")
#[1] "2007"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response - this works perfectly (will accept your answer asap). One more question though. Do you have, by any chance, a source or a link of how to derive/learn this? I had some trouble finding an introduction online.

Comment: @PatrickBalada  Thank you for the response.  I think [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) would be a good starting point

Answer (score 6):

You may use a `sub` option, too:

```
some_string <- "1_2_start_2007_3_end"
sub(".*_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", some_string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GMZFfO/1)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(\\d{4})` - Group 1 (referred to via `\1` from the replacement pattern): 4 digits
- `_.*` - a `_` and then any 0+ chars up to the end of string.

**NOTE**: akrun's `str_extract(some_string, "(?<=_)\\d{4}")` will extract the *leftmost* occurrence and my `sub(".*_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", some_string)` will extract the *rightmost* occurrence of a 4-digit substring enclosed with `_`. For my my solution to return the *leftmost* one use a lazy quantifier with the first `.`: `sub(".*?_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", some_string)`.

[R test](https://ideone.com/3hyjeK):

```
some_string <- "1_2018_start_2007_3_end"
sub(".*?_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", some_string) # leftmost
## -> 2018
sub(".*_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", some_string) # rightmost
## -> 2007
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Especially thank you for the detailed explanation of the different parts of the regex and the link!

Answer (score 2):

Just to get a non-regex approach out there, in which we split on `_` and convert to numeric. All non-numbers will be coerced to NA, so we use `!is.na` to eliminate them. We then use `nchar` to count the characters, and pull the one with 4.

```
i1 <- as.numeric(strsplit(some_string, '_')[[1]])
i1 <- i1[!is.na(i1)]

i1[nchar(i1) == 4]
#[1] 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest regex I could come up with:

```
\S.*_(\d{4})_\S.*
```

It means,

- any number of non-space characters,
- then _
- followed by four digits (d{4})
- above four digits is your year captured using **()**
- another _
- any other gibberish non space string

Since, you mentioned you're new, please test this and all other answers at https://regex101.com/, pretty good to learn regex, it explains in depth what your regex is actually doing.

If you just care about *(year)* then below regex is enough:

```
_(\d{4})_
```